# Rails JSON API: limit has_many relationship to current_user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails json API with 2 models (`Bags` and `Items`). I am using active record serializers with MySQL to organize the json output. I want to show all `Bags` for all users, but only `Items` for the current user.

Looking for something like this:

```
class Bag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items,-> {where current_user: "#{current_user.id}"},class_name: 'Items'
end
```

I don't know of a way to pass the `current_user.id` property to the model. Hoping someone knows a way.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You can't access controller and helper methods directly in your models. You need to pass them to your model. An easy way of doing it would be to add a method or a scope.
2. Association query customization **does not** support argument passing to your block (`-> {where current_user: ...`). So, you can't do it in association declaration.

So, I guess you would have to add a scope:

```
class Bag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  scope :user_items, ->(user) { where(items: {current_user: user}) }
end
```

PS. You don't need to convert `"#{current_user.id}"` to a string.

Comment: Yea, left the "#{curent_user.id}" in for example purposes. Just didn't change it for this example. But where is the "->(user)" argument getting passed from? The controller?

Comment: Doesn't matter. You can call it anywhere and pass an instance of your user: `Bag.user_items(current_user)`.